# Image in Java applet won't show up

Tags: java, image, graphics, applet

I have a project due Sunday (in school) and I am having problems showing images.

Everything else but the image is working, I used code examples from many people but none of them worked.

I put the image saved as "car.png" in the project directory.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

It's a project where I need to make a Java Applet that shows a street with a few buildings, a road and a car on the road, but I can't get the car image to show.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;



public class App_Main extends Applet
    {
    House[] h;
    private Image img;

    public void init()
    {
        Private v1 = new Private(120,300,80);
        Private v2 = new Private(180,300,80);
        Building b1 = new Building(300,300,80,5);
        img = getImage(getCodeBase(),"car.png");


        h= new House[3];

        h[0] = v1;
        h[1] = v2;
        h[2] = b1;
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        Private v1 = new Private(120, 300, 50);
        Private v2 = new Private(180, 300, 50);
        Building b1 = new Building(300, 300, 80, 5);


        House[] h = new House[3];

        h[0] = v1;
        h[1] = v2;
        h[2] = b1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            h[i].paintHouse(g);
        }

        //start road

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.drawLine(0, 370, 1000, 370);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 371, 1000, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, 520, 1000, 520);
        for (int x=0; x < 1000; x += 100)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(x+25, 430, 50, 20);
        }

        //end road

        g.drawImage(img,50,50,this);



    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: the code compiles and everything (no errors) but the image simply isn't shown..

Comment: You should `sysout` the `getCodeBase()` to check whether you have the file i.e. `car.png` available on the same location.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

1. You're using an [Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html)

   > Applets are an advanced and specialized type of app. that has little place in the real world around us

   See Andrew Thompson's post [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java Applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) to read more about this.

   Instead you should try using Java Swing also covered on the above recommended post.
2. You're overriding `paint()` (w/o adding the `@Override` annotation) method of the `Applet`, instead you should have a `JPanel` and `@Override` it's `paintComponent()` method and then let the `Applet` display the `JPanel` I said before, as stated in this Hovercraft's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13708219/2180785)
3. Related to the above point, you're not calling `super.paint()` method of the `Applet` class
4. You don't know if your `img` is in your code base, so debug your application (with a debugger or some `System.out.println()` calls and check if the path for `car.png` is correct.

For better help sooner please post a valid [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which includes the `House` class if needed or simply draws an image.

Also as a side recommendation don't use underscores (`_`) to separate words in your classes' names (`App_Main` could be written as `AppMain`, it's not a big deal, but it's a [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))